# PHP MySQL input HTML tags

Tags: php, mysql, html, tags, format

I have a PHP MySQL database which I will be storing all my information in. I have a text field on a HTML page that the user can add data to and then on submit a MySQL query inserts this information into a database. Pretty standard stuff.

However, I am now in a position where I can attach a TinyMCE or FCKEditor onto my text field (now a text area). My question is: How do I get this information into the database now, taking into account that the tags will affect the MySQL query, and stripping any tags would impair the display of said information on another page?

I know about strip_tags and similar PHP features but my problem isn't going to be with the PHP it's going to be with the database input with MySQL, any " or '  or ; will break the query and removing these tags before input would remove any format enhancements the user has made.

I am under the assumption also, that if I use mysql_real_escape_string I would need to strip the slashes before I display the data - and this would take all the slashes out of the close tags as well: , 
 etc.

Comment: ` taking into account that the tags will affect the MySQL query...` why? What happens that will cause this? If you escape the incoming data properly (which is vital for security reasons anyway) that shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the value before you insert it in your SQL statement. If you use the mysql extension, you use the `mysql_real_escape_string` to do this:

```
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
```

It escapes characters such as quotation marks, so you can safely insert the value in database.

Comment: I thought that on the otherside (i.e. when I'm displaying the data in the database), I'd need to strip slashes, and upon stripping the slashes all the close tags </a> and <br /> would have their slashes removed as well, impairing the format of the data. I mean I already have mysql_real_escape_string on things like user input but thought there may be another method I could use for this particular situation

Comment: You _never_ need to use stripslashes on a properly configured webserver. They were used back when magic quotes were used in PHP, but they've been deprecated for a while now. Also `stripslashes` strips backslashes, not `/`, so tags like `</a>` would be unaffected anyway.

Comment: so how would I output this data then? I wouldn't want all the escape slashes in my output

Comment: There should be no slashes. `mysql_real_escape_string` only adds slashes so that the query won't break. There will be no slashes in the actual value stored in the database.

Comment: I gave it a quick test and unfortunately the slashes ARE stored in the database. I'll have to use strip slashes on display

Comment: Then you probably have magic quotes on (which you really really should not have on). Confirm with `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc());` If it returns true, then you should really turn it off in your php.ini. If it returns false, you're double escaping your input, and need to find where that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```